# NativeFirebaseError: [storage/unknown] The server has terminated the upload session

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload my image to the firestore and getting this error

my file path is already there:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.contact.smooth/files/Pictures/8835e5ad-fb47- 
4f0d-ad47-97690f4fb41a.jpg
```

image uploading code:

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

export default file => onSuccess => onError => {
  const path = 'contact-pictures/user/777/' + file.modificationDate;

  const ref = storage().ref(path);

  console.log('file.path', file.path)

 const task = ref.putFile(file.path);

 task
   .then(async () => {
   try {
    console.log("success in uploading file")
    const url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    console.log('url calling on onsuccess', url)
    onSuccess(url);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error)
  }
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log("____________Error in uploading file")
  onError(error);
});
};
```

My storage rules

```
rules_version = '2';
  service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if true;
   }
  }
}
```

please help

Comment: Cloud Storage (for storing files) and Cloud Firestore (for storing documents) are two completely separate products. You are calling the Cloud Storage API through Firebase, but are showing the rules for Cloud Firestore, which have no effect on such file operations. If you think the security rules are causing the problem, edit your question to show the rules you've set for Cloud Storage in Firebase.

Comment: ok I got it, Does it means I am not using firestore? but some different storage api?

Comment: If you search the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs) for the product names I mentioned, you should've found: [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) and [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore).

Comment: Did this allow you to make progress and fix the problem you had?

Comment: I haven't worked on it till now, I will let you know if I get a related problem

Comment: Hi, I tried it, and its working fine, Thanks for the help :)